# Show empty rows and columns in sklearn ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I want to display a confusion matrix on label prediction. On certain subsets of my data, some classes are missing (from both the ground truth and prediction), eg class 6 in the example below.

I would like to still show the `6` line and column even if filled with zeros. Is there a way to achieve this with sklearn's `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` ?

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


GT   = [4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]
pred = [4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(GT, pred,
                                        cmap='Blues',
                                        ax=ax,)
plt.show()
```

I have tried to pass my list of labels to the `display_labels` argument, but it fails because the length does not match the number of classes that is actually in the data

```
GT   = [4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]
pred = [4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(GT, pred,
                                        cmap='Blues',
                                        ax=ax,
                                        display_labels = range(8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from_estimator` and `from_predictions` methods have a `labels` argument to set the labels directly, overriding what's in the data. See the full list of options in the [docs page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions).